# Android- Intent.ACTION_CALL is not working for phone no started with "911"

Tags: android, android-intent, action, phone-call

Below code is working fine **except those phone numbers which are started with "911"**. It's opening default dialer app.

```
String phoneNo = "911XXXXXXX"; 
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo)); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Please note, a**ndroid.permission.CALL_PHONE** already added in AndroidManifest.xml file. Also, this app used in India.

Any reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_CALL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_CALL):

> Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.

In the US, and perhaps elsewhere, 911 is an emergency number.